# Can't cope with expected identifier

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a tetris. Well, my glass (QtGlass.h) creates a figure.
I would like to use a parameter here to specify which shape the figure should 
take.

Could you suggest me why parameters cause this error:

```
QtGlass.h:29:23: error: expected identifier before 'L'
QtGlass.h:29:23: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'L'
```

I've shown in the comments below where this error occurs.
By the way, if I uncomment the lines which signigy a parameterless variant,
it works.

```
**Figure.h**
class Figure : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
...
public:
    Figure(char Shape);
    //Figure();
...
};

**Figure.cpp**
Figure::Figure(char Shape) {
//Figure::Figure() {   
    previous_shape = 1;
    colour = RED;
    ...
}

**QtGlass.h**
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
...
protected:
    Figure the_figure('L'); //QtGlass.h:29:23: error: expected identifier before 'L' QtGlass.h:29:23: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'L'
    //Figure the_figure;
...
};
```

**Edded later**

When I use this:

```
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
    QtGlass() : the_figure('L') {}


I get this:

QtGlass.cpp:164:50: error: no matching function for call to 'Figure::Figure()'
QtGlass.cpp:164:50: note: candidates are:
Figure.h:38:5: note: Figure::Figure(char)
Figure.h:38:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Figure.h:20:7: note: Figure::Figure(const Figure&)
Figure.h:20:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

**QtGlass.cpp**

```
QtGlass::QtGlass(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent) {
    key_pressed = false;
    coord_x = 5;
    coord_y = 5;
    arrow_n = 0;
    highest_line = 21;
    this->initialize_glass();
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(moveDownByTimer()));
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize a member object using that syntax. If your compiler supports C++11's uniform initialization syntax or in-class initialization of member variables you can do this:

```
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
...
protected:
    Figure the_figure{'L'};
    // or
    Figure the_figure = 'L'; // works because Figure(char) is not explicit
...
};
```

Otherwise you need to initialize the object within `QtGlass`' constructor initializer list

```
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
...
protected:
    Figure the_figure;
...
};

// in QtGlass.cpp
QtGlass::QtGlass(QWidget *parent) 
: QFrame(parent)
, the_figure('L')
{}
```

Comment: could you have a look at another error that appears when I did what you suggested (I added some to the initial post). By the way, the compiler is c++98.

Comment: @Trts That error doesn't match the code you've posted. I'd expect that error if you wrote `QtGlass() : the_figure() {}` instead of `QtGlass() : the_figure('L') {}`. Make sure you're including *Figure.h* in *QtGlass.h*. Also, what compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I've doulblechecked. Figure.h is included.The compiler is GCC 4.6.2 (MinGW).

Comment: @Trts I misread the error message, didn't realize it was the constructor definition in *QtGlass.cpp* causing the error, apologies for the confusion. I've updated my answer; this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an instance of `Figure` in the definition of `QtGlass` which is not allowed. You have to instantiate `the_figure` in the constructor of `QtGlass`:

```
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
    QtGlass() {
        the_figure = Figure('L');
    };
...
protected:
    Figure the_figure;
...
};
```